# Loading AutoComplete VAR from SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jquery-ui, sharepoint-2010

I am stuck - I am trying to do something tricky.  I need to load a JQuery-UI AutoComplete "Source" with a specific SharePoint 2010 REST column.  There are 300 items that need to be loaded and I can't seem to figure out how to do so.  I was able to get a drop down to populate the list items but not sure how to get the source: availableTags portion to work.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request,response) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/BagDetails?",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()},
      success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
          var list = result.Bag;
          response(list);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Started with:

```
var availableTags = [
  "Bag0","Bag1","Bag2"
];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

Comment: Can you edit and provide a small sample of the data that is returned? Also, you re-populate `list` each loop, that's not going to work.

Comment: The data that is return is a SharePoint 2010 REST XML webpage.

<d:BagValue>Bag01</d:BagValue>

Answer (score 0):

I would try an adjustment to your success function:

```
success: function (data) {
  var list = [];
  $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
    list.push(result.Bag);
  });
  response(list);
}
```

You need to assemble an array to return to Response.